# How to set Android property when package name itself is more than 31 characters

Tags: android, android-activity, adb, valgrind

Since the android property name length limit is 31 chars and it returns 'could not set property' error when the length exceeds 31 chars.

The package name of app I am working is itself is 28 chars and while trying to set any property (for example: setprop wrap.pkg.name.which.is.very.long "logwrapper valgrind") command fails.

Is there any hack/WAR to do this ?

Comment: What do you think about **Refactoring** your _package name_?

Comment: I don't own the app.